# Dual boot - Installed second OS - can't see the original

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu/Arch linux. I originally had just Ubuntu on my PC. I then made another partition to install Arch on and followed the Arch wiki and [also this resource](https://github.com/jieverson/dotfiles/wiki/arch-linux-for-dummies).

After following the instructions when I rebooted my PC it now takes me to the GRUB2 menu and all I can see is the new Arch installation.

How can I add the original Ubuntu install?

I have tried doing `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to restore the GRUB config but it appears that it doesn't detect the Ubuntu OS.

I suspect maybe when [I followed this step about UEFI workarounds](https://github.com/jieverson/dotfiles/wiki/arch-linux-for-dummies#boot-loader) I may have overriden an existing configuration?

Any suggestions on where I go from here? Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of grub and use [systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) (which is way easier to configure than heavyweight grub) from arch. I really don't understand why crappy distros like ubuntu still force use of grub on EFI-able computers.